# Is the 'React way' really to re-render the whole react-leaflet component regularly?

Tags: react-leaflet

I'm using `react-leaflet` to display a map with dynamic markers loaded from an API. Until now, I've been loading the Markers in the render, but I realised this was rendering unnecessarily re-rending the whole Leaflet Map each time anything changed (e.g. zoom, location). I think I can remove my zoom and location state and call native Leaflet functions for these, but ultimately I need to load my data after initial render, resulting a second unnecessary render in the very least. Is React really designed so that this is the preferred way?

```
function MyMap() {
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect');

    getMyData().then(a => {
      console.log('data load');
      setMarkers(a);
    });
  }, []);

  console.log('map render');
  return (
    <Map id='map' className='map' center={[52, 0]} zoom={6}>
      <TileLayer
        url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
      <LayerGroup>
        {markers.map(a => {
          return (
            <Marker
              key={a._id}
              position={[a.location.latitude, a.location.longitude]}
              icon={myIcon}
            />
          );
        })}
      </LayerGroup>
    </Map>
  );
}
```

Console output:

```
map render
useEffect
data load
map render
```

I was tempted to fix this by dynamically adding markers in the normal Leaflet way:

```
L.marker([50.5, 30.5]).addTo(map);
```

but this appears non-trivial in `react-leaflet`. In looking for how to dynamically add Markers I came across React Leaflet: Add markers dynamically, specifically the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42848613) suggesting that shouldn't be done. The associated jsfiddle re-renders the whole map for each click. Perhaps that's fine?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent map re-render once marker is added the following list of changes could be applied:

a) in a `MyMap` (parent) component in `markers` state keep track *only* a markers loaded from data source

> Note: `markers` state is not getting updated once map is clicked in this component

```
function MyMap() {
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");
    getMyData().then((data) => {
      console.log("data load");
      setMarkers(data);
    });
  }, []);

  console.log("map render");
  return (
    <Map id="map" className="map" center={[52, 0]} zoom={4}>
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
      <MyLayer defaultMarkers={markers} />
    </Map>
  );
}
```

b) introduce a separate (child) component with `markers` state to keep track of 
markers loaded from data source (set it with a *default value* passed via `props`) along with a markers added on map `click` event:

```
function MyLayer(props, ref) {
  const { defaultMarkers } = props;
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState(defaultMarkers);
  const mapProps = useLeaflet();


  const addMarker = useCallback((e) => {
    const newMarker = {
      location: e.latlng,
    };
    console.log(newMarker);
    setMarkers((existingMarkers) => [...existingMarkers, newMarker]);
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    setMarkers(defaultMarkers);  
    mapProps.map.on('click',addMarker)
  }, [addMarker,mapProps,defaultMarkers]);


  return (
    <LayerGroup>
      {markers.map((marker, idx) => {
        return (
          <Marker
            key={idx}
            position={[marker.location.lat, marker.location.lng]}
          />
        );
      })}
    </LayerGroup>
  );
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-t9tep7)