# Dynamically add circles to react leaflet with blockchain

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, use-state, react-leaflet, ethers.js

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42835692/react-leaflet-add-markers-dynamically) post which partly answers my question, but my problem is the infinite loop that the `provider.on` method creates with `setData(_data)`. I simply want to update the circle information to be rendered from my local blockchain, but the `setData(_data)` call creates an infinite loop.

I have tried using a global variable instead of using `useState`, which solves the infinite loop, but this updated value cannot be seen in other parts of the code.

```
function App() {
  const initialPos = [55, 12];
  const zoomLv = 13;
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const greeterAddress = "0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3"
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("http://localhost:8545");
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(greeterAddress, Greeter.abi, provider)

provider.on("block", async (blockNumber) => {
  const _data = await contract.getCircle().split(", ") //[lat, lng, radius]
  setData(_data)
}); 

function RenderCircle() {
  if (data.length > 1) {
    return <Circle center={[parseFloat(data[0]), parseFloat(data[1])]} radius={parseFloat(data[2])} />
  }
  return null
}

  return (
    <>
      <MapContainer center={initialPos} zoom={zoomLv} id='map'>
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/osmfr/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          maxZoom={20}
        />
        <RenderCircle/>
      </MapContainer>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you have a demo to reproduce this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To solve it, I made it a react component class, and used its `setState()` instead of using `useState()`. This avoided the infinite loop.

Comment: you have to use useEffect hook

Comment: if you want I can help you to implement it, just let's make a live coding session ?

Comment: Thanks for your offer @UladzKha but the infinite loop also happened with `useEffect`, and my current implementation solved my issue (refactor the component into a class instead of using hooks). Not sure why I get downvoted for explaining what solved my issue.