# React Leaflet: Marker icon during selecting position when add markers dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I implement dynamically adding markers using [Evan Siroky answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42848613/13100727).
Now I want a marker to follow my cursor when I'm looking for an appropriate position for him. Like in this website after clicking the "Add Court" button. Example in gif.

[Marker following cursor example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jOlI.gif)

Could you give me some examples of something similar to my case? Or some suggestions on how could I implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with some `CSS` and `JS`

when you push the button you add the class and then you remove

Here an example to start

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.DomUtil.addClass(map._container,'cursor');

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
    .openPopup();
```

```css
#map { width: 100%; height: 360px; }

.leaflet-container.cursor {
  cursor: url("https://i.imgur.com/NyfJiPA.png"), auto;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-hoalWLoI8r4UszCkZ5kL8vayOGVae1oxXe/2A4AO6J9+580uKHDO3JdHb7NzwwzK5xr/Fs0W40kiNHxM9vyTtQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-BB3hKbKWOc9Ez/TAwyWxNXeoV9c1v6FIeYiBieIWkpLjauysF18NzgR1MBNBXf8/KABdlkX68nAhlwcDFLGPCQ=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
   
    <div id="map"></div>
```